# Mobile usability issues reported by Google at Search Console

Tags: css, responsive-design, google-search-appliance, google-search-console, google-console-developer

Our website is responsive but it is showing the below mobile usability issues at Google search console.

1. Content wider than scree
2. Clickable elements too close together

When tested using mobile friendly testing tool, all the affected pages are not showing any errors.

Example - https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly?id=N40RS1lHRoz3As9IHqJv2g

Even we are not seeing any errors in Live Test.

Please check and let me know if we are missing something here.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever get an answer?

Answer (score -1):

This area is for questions about the Google Search Appliance - not about Google Search.  Sorry.